# Unable to run Bash Script in Cronjob on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting, crontab

Below script can execute from normal user but I can't able to run script through cronjob on macos(bigsur): Following error comes when script is executing through job security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

```
#!/bin/sh

keychainItem="connectvpn"
# this name has to match "Account" for the entry you make in keychain
VPNName="DIS CVPN"   # match the name of the VPN service to run
function isnt_connected () {
 scutil --nc status "$VPNName" | sed -n 1p | grep -qv Connected
}

get_pw () {
   security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga $keychainItem \
   |ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: "(.*)"$/'
}



echo "fetching VPN credentials from keychain account \"$keychainItem\""
echo "Using VPN service: $VPNName"

if isnt_connected $VPNName; then
 echo "Connecting to VPN..."
 scutil --nc start "$VPNName"
 sleep 1
 osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke tab"
 osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"$(get_pw)\""
 osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return"
else
 echo "Already Connected to VPN..."
fi
```

Here's my crontab line:

```
*/1 * * * * /Users/demo/vpn/connect.sh >> /Users/demo/vpn/vpnlog.log 2>&1
```

Comment: I am not familiar with apples, but you might need to specify full paths for the commands in your script as cron (at least on linux) ignores your PATH variable.

Comment: I already used full paths but its not working.

Comment: When I use the `security` command in my shell to read a password, a pop-up window appears saying "security wants to use your confidential info... To allow this, enter the login keychain password."  I get this even after using the `security unlock-keychain` command (which requires my password in the Terminal).  So, unless you've found another way to unlock your keychain that doesn't require you to enter your password interactively (in the Terminal, or in the pop-up), I don't think you can put this in a cronjob.

Comment: Its already unlocked. And easily fetched information from root terminal: `sudo -H -u username bash -c  "security find-generic-password -w -s vpnpass -a vpnpass"`

Comment: It also work when i su username and run : `security find-generic-password -w -s vpnpass -a vpnpass`
It gives me correct output. 
But in cronjob script its not working.